# Link to issue page from within Phabricator

Tags: issue-tracking, phabricator

We've been using Phabricator for post-commit code reviews (aka Audits) for some months now. When doing a commit we also attach an **issue number** ("Issue: XXXX").

The issue tracker url for this issue is:

```
site.com/issue/XXXX
```

I'm wondering if there's any way we could configure Phabricator to replace this text with a hyperlink to its corresponding `URL` when viewing the commit's comment from Phabricator.

Comment: Good luck finding that answer ;)

Comment: What is the issue tracker? Asana, JIRA, and Maniphest are included.

Comment: It was developed internally, so it's not one of the popular ones. We are evaluating migrating to use either JIRA or Maniphest. The link to the issue on the legacy issue tracker would be very useful when viewing old issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First step**

Go to the configuration interface at `<your-hosted-phabricator>/config/all/`.

**Second step**

Edit the following two parameters:

1. In `bugtraq.logregex` set:

   ```
   /[Ii]ssues?:?(\s*,?\s*\d+)+/
   /(\d+)/
   ```
2. In `bugtraq.url` set:

   ```
   https://<your-issue-tracker>/issue/%BUGID%
   ```

If you are using these same config settings for another tracking system, you will have to pick and choose.  But, we found this very useful when linking to an unsupported bug tracking system.

You should be able to replace the url to your local system's url and build your own regex that will match your "Issue: XXXX" commit message.

Good Luck!

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but would those parameters go in `conf/default.conf.php`? I tried with [this](https://gist.github.com/juandiana/f5f87b61957f4a5870cd) but didn't seem to work (restarted phabricator to make sure changes applied).

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect the whole file for added clarity.  we do have this in the default.conf.php file.

Comment: Thank you very much @CEPA! It's working nicely now. I found that I could also edit these parameters from the web interface, where it also explains each parameters and gives examples. I edited the post to reflect this.